# Native Date Picker - how to show calendar by default?

Tags: html, google-chrome, input, calendar, datepicker

According to:
http://tjvantoll.com/2012/06/30/creating-a-native-html5-datepicker-with-a-fallback-to-jquery-ui/

I have set this up (simple) but the question is, how do I make the calendar show at all times? As of right now, one must click the dropdown to display the graphic calendar.

Thank you so much and I appreciate the help in advance!
*chrome*

Answer (score 0):

Using the native html5 datepicker, there is no way to force a display.

If you need to have control over the calendar, you could always use any datepicker plugin for jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look to the answer from Sankar Jay. I tested and works fine.

Html:

```
<input id="datepicker" type="text">
```

Jquery:

```
$(function() {
$('.ui-datepicker').css('display','none');
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
}).datepicker("setDate", "0");
})
```

Here is the link:

http://jsfiddle.net/3hA5n/1/

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can use [afarkas](http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/index.html#Forms-forms-ext), which gives you this option by using this markup.
Check this

```
<input type="date" data-date-inline-picker="true" />
```